# How to generate Xml or Json Output Format from Xml raw string?

Tags: c#, json, xml, .net-core, format

I'm trying to make use of FormatFilter to generate 'json' or 'xml' controller response output.

The problem is that my starting point it's a random (well-formed) xml string.

I'm using DotNet Core 2.2 and this is what I have right now in controller:

```
        [HttpGet("values.{format}"), FormatFilter]
        public ActionResult TestObjectOutput()
        {
            string xml = DynamicXmlRawString();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc);
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);

            return Ok(obj);
        }

        public static string DynamicXmlRawString()
        {
            return $@"<Result><DateTime>{DateTime.Now}</DateTime><User><Someone>12345678</Someone></User></Result>";
        }
```

The output response for **json** is coming as expected.

`$ curl -i -X GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/values/object.json`

`{"Result":{"DateTime":"27/04/2019 16:31:27","User":{"Someone":"12345678"}}}`

The response for **xml** returns **HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable**

`curl -i -X GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/values/object.xml`

Server error:

`An error occurred while trying to create an XmlSerializer for the type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'.`

Expected result:

`<Result><DateTime>27/04/2019 16:40:05</DateTime><User><Someone>12345678</Someone></User></Result>`

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use the model class (which represents the XML) instead of ExpandoObject? For example, dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);

Comment: No, because it's an "anonymous" xml document. I don't know the xml schema in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was overthinking...problem solved.

```
        [HttpGet("values.{format}"), FormatFilter]
        public ActionResult TestObjectOutput()
        {
            string xml = DynamicXmlRawString();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

            return Ok(xmlDoc);
        }

        public static string DynamicXmlRawString()
        {
            return $@"<Result><DateTime>{DateTime.Now}</DateTime><User><Someone>12345678</Someone></User></Result>";
        }
```